# Computing the Gauss map

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider the surface 
$$x^2+y^2-z^2=0$$
To determine whether it is regular or not the the hint said to compute the Gaussian map.
I don’t understand why that is the go to method since the computation can get very tedious at times.
I also do not understand how it can help to determine the regularity in the first place.

Comment: What formula for the Gauss map are you using?

Comment: For chart r the gauss map N is $N=\frac{r_u x r_v}{ |r_u xr_v|}$